# I killed everyone in Almeria in Avernum 4. Is there any way to restore the town?

Tags: avernum-4

In Avernum 4 (Spiderweb Software), before completing one of the main story quests, everyone in Almeria attacks the player's characters on sight. I thought I had to fight my way through Almeria to access the rest of the Great Cave, but later I completed the afore-mentioned quest.

Now Almeria is open to me, but all the townspeople are dead. Is there a way I can edit my save file to reset that area, or will I have to start the game all over again?

Comment: I know from experience that its hard to get Spiderweb Software games questions answered here since it doesn't seem like many of the fans frequent Arqade. I recommend also dropping a post [on the game's forums](http://spiderwebforums.ipbhost.com/index.php?/forum/22-second-avernum-trilogy/)... They're pretty friendly and helpful there and it tends to be where I end up getting my answers.